# What types of analysis will work on a dataset of medians?

Tags: regression, median

The dataset I currently have is wages for different occupations across different geographical regions, however each observation is a median.

For example, a doctor in region A, the wage reported would be the median wage of all doctors in region A. I have this for a number of different regions and occupations. In total, there are 500 occupations and 38 different regions across 8 years, and I do not have access to the original data from which these medians were calculated.

My question is how valid will analysis on this data be? Even summary statistics such as finding the median wage across all jobs in a particular region would be taking the median of medians which I have been told is not a good method. Would a regression have inaccurate results because of this data structure as well? I am feeling like this data has really good potential but may not be suitable for analysis and any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the analysis, the problem is interpreting the analysis. There's nothing inherently wrong with taking the median, but it's hard to know what that might mean.

Comment: Yes, interpretation is ultimately the end goal here, which is why I am doubting this dataset. I want to have something that makes sense at the end of the day and have not been able to find anything related to a dataset like this.

Comment: _Analysis_ is vague and unhelpful terminology. Analyze which to find out what might provide the basis for a substantive answer. // What comparisons do you want to make? Doctors make more than carpenters? Doctors in Dallas make less than doctors in NYC? Earnings of lawyers are higher in LA than in Seattle? Earnings go up as metro area population increases? // Do you know the sample sizes on which each median was based?

Comment: Medians of large samples tend to be normally distributed. This 'CLT for medians' holds provided the PDF of the population is positive at the population median. The SD of such a sample median decreases with increasing $n.$

Comment: Actually in this case there is high kurtosis and a positive skew, not normal whatsoever. This follows other, known distributions of wages though, which gives me confidence that the data is fairly accurate.

Comment: I don't know if the OP is still looking, but, my question (like that of @BruceET is "what do you want to find out"?